# Extracting pattern from infinite loop python

Tags: python, loops, pattern-matching, infinite-loop

I have an infinite loop that is giving me a string each loop. I know that the given string follows a pattern. I need to get that pattern and represent the loop as a formula.

Let's use an example to see it better:

1- "126"

2- "1236"

3- "12346"

4- "1234526"

5- "12345236"

6- "123452346"

7- "12345234526"

8- "123452345236"

9- "1234523452346"

...

As you may se the loop pattern can be represented as :

- `"1(A*n)26"`
- `"1(A*n)236"`
- `"1(A*n)2346"`

being `A="2345"` and `n` a number from 0 to infinite.

I've wrote this code but I don't know if it would be the most optimized code or if it will fail in edge cases:

```
def find_repeated(s):
    for j in range(len(s)):
        for i in range(j):
            if s[i:j] == s[j:2*j - i]:
                return s[i:j]
```

Cheers

Comment: The pattern is not very clear. So, the starting value is `1` and ending value is `6` always and the `2345` will be inserted one char at a time?

Comment: Do you mean that your pattern follows P(A*n)Q and you want to find A from a single sample string ?

Comment: the pattern can be either "1(A*n)26"
"1(A*n)236"
"1(A*n)2346"